# Program to read a 4-digit integer and output the sum of the digits

Tags: c, scanf

I'm stuck with an assignment in an introduction course to programming. We are using C. The assignment is:

> write a program which asks the user for a four digit INTEGER and outputs the sum of the four digits in the integer.

I have tried different thing but when I test the program it doesn't work. When I compile it, I get no error so when I go ahead and test it, it won't give me the right answer. I've tried different things and it just gives me a different answer but it's still the wrong one.

I was given this to test the program: enter 1234 when asked to enter four digit integer and answer has to be 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int sum,digit1,digit2,digit3,digit4;
    printf("enter four digit integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &digit1,&digit2,&digit3,&digit4);

    digit1=(digit1%1000)/10;
    digit2=(digit2%1000)/10;
    digit3=(digit3%1000)/10;
    digit4=(digit4%1000)/10;

    /*calculation*/
    sum=digit1+digit2+digit3+digit4;

    printf ("answer is: %d\n",sum);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: try taking the variables as float

Comment: I think your problems will be clear to you if you try and print out some intermediate values.  Try printing digits right after scanf, and then individually before summing.

Comment: Hints: You need to decide whether you want to read the 4 numbers as *one* integer into one variable, or whether you want to read each into its own variable. Right now you are mixing and matching. Try printing out each digit and see what your values are.

Comment: So I would need a scanf and printf for every digit?

Comment: @aquinas Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100).

Comment: @DwB Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100).

Answer (score 3):

One problem is this

```
scanf("%d%d%d%d", &digit1,&digit2,&digit3,&digit4);
```

otherwise you are reading only one digit

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf).

But ... better do it like this

```
scanf("%d", &number);
sum  = 0;
do 
{
    //get a digit 
    sum += number % 10;
    //remove the digit  
    number /= 10;
} while (number > 0);
print ("%d", sum);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I had but I was still having the same problem. Actually, when I do that(I just tried that again) when I test the program it doesn't give me an answer at all.

Comment: can you give me the exact program ... and what number did you enter ? and what compiler are you using ?

Comment: ssh secure shell. When I compile it, I get no errors. when I test it with the numbers 1234, it is supposed to give me 10 as an aswer but it doesn't. I actually also included modulus now so it looks like this  int sum,digit1,digit2,digit3,digit4;
printf("enter four digit integer:\n");
scanf("%d" ,&digit1,&digit2,&digit3,&digit4);

digit1=(digit1%10000/1000);
digit2=(digit2%1000/100);
digit3=(digit3%100/10);
digit4=(digit4%10/1);

Answer (score 3):

When you read the user input, you read it as one number:

```
printf("enter four digit integer:\n");
scanf("%d", &digit1,&digit2,&digit3,&digit4);
```

should be:

```
printf("enter four digit integer:\n");
scanf("%d", &number);
```

Next you need to extract the individual digits from the number read, using the `%` and `/` operators and finally add them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `scanf`, which expects a formatter `%d` for every argument you pass it.

So instead of this:

```
scanf("%d", &digit1,&digit2,&digit3,&digit4);
```

You should have this (if you enter the digits separately with a white space between them) :

```
scanf("%d", &digit1);
scanf("%d", &digit2);
scanf("%d", &digit3);
scanf("%d", &digit4);
```

This will read in four different `int`s.  If you want one integer read in and then extract the individual digits, then this is enough:

```
scanf("%d", &digit1);
```

`int  scanf ( const char * format, ... );`

> Returns the number of fields successfully converted and assigned

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y6s16x1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Note, though, that the digits have to be whitespace separated, or they will all end up in `digit1`.

Comment: what do you mean by whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n, rem;
    int sum=0;

    printf("enter a no.");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    while(n!=0)
    {
        rem = n%10;
        sum += rem;
        n=n/10;
    }

    printf("sum is=%d\n",sum);
}
```

Comment: I doubt this will compile, if it does then please enter information as to _why_ this code will help the OP

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no need to take input in four integer variables to [find sum of digits of a number](http://codeforwin.blogspot.in/2015/06/c-program-to-calculate-sum-of-digits.html).

It needs to be done in this way

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()  
{  
    int num, sum=0;  

    /* 
     * Reads a number from user 
     */  
    printf("Enter any number to find sum of its digit: ");  
    scanf("%d", &num);  

    /* 
     * Finds the sum of digits  
     */  
    while(num!=0)  
    {  
        /* Find the last digit from num and add to sum */  
        sum += num % 10;

        /* Removes last digit from num as its work has been done*/  
        num = num / 10;  
    }  

    printf("\nSum of digits = %d", sum);  

    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here below is based upon my technique. It's done through mathematical break-down of the number and then printing out individual result. Here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()

{   //Code Begins
//Variable Initialization
int digit, dig1, dig2, dig3, dig4,digi, sum;
//Acquiring input
printf("Enter 4-Digit Number:\n");
scanf("%d", &digit);
//Number resolution technique
//Digit at 1000th place
dig1 = (digit/1000);
printf ("Digit at 1000th place is: %d \n", dig1);
//Digit at 100th place
dig2 = (digit-(dig1*1000))/100;
printf ("Digit at 100th place is: %d \n", dig2);
//Digit at 10th place
digi = ((digit/100)*100);
dig3 = (digit-digi)/10;
printf ("Digit at 10th place is: %d \n", dig3);
//Digit at unit place
dig4 = ((digit-((digit/10)*10)));
printf ("Digit at unit place is: %d \n", dig4 );
//Sum of Digits
sum = dig1+dig2+dig3+dig4;
printf ("Sum of digits in the number is: %d \n\n", sum);
//Self Applaud
printf ("Isn't it Awesome ! A big hand of applaud for my technique !!! \n\n\n");
system ("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for simplicity, something like this will do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

int sum,num,digit1,digit2,digit3,digit4;
printf("enter four digit integer:\n");
scanf("%d",&num);

digit1=(num/1000);
digit2=(num%1000)/100;
digit3=(num%100)/10;
digit4=(num%1000)%10;

/*calculation*/
sum=digit1+digit2+digit3+digit4;

printf("answer is: %d\n",sum);
return (0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

output comes right when user enter only 4 numbers.
when user add more than 4 no's then output differ......

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

void main()
{

```
int num,d1,d2,d3,d4,sum;

printf("\nEnter the four digits you wish to add: ");

scanf("%d",&num);

d1=num%10;
num=num/10;
d2=num%10;
num=num/10;
d3=num%10;
d4=num/10;

sum=d1+d2+d3+d4;

printf("\n*The sum of four digits is: %d*",sum);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//writing program to read four digit integer and print the sum of its digits
//by nirav adatiya
main()
{
    int num,a,b,c,d,result;
    printf("enter four digit number for sum ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    a=num%10;
    b=num%100/10;
    c=num%1000/100;
    d=num%10000/1000;
    result=a+b+c+d;
    printf("so\na=%d\nb=%d\nc=%d\nd=%d",a,b,c,d);
    printf("\nresult is%d ",result);
}
```